# How can I pass a string array created in my Javascript to C# code behind file?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, ajax, client-server

I have an array MyArray[] in my Javascript that is created dynamically. I now need to pass this array into my C sharp code behind file. This is because I want to write the contents of this array into a .txt file which is saved on the server. I am a beginner in web and until this point I hadn't gotten to the point where I've had to communicate back and forth between client and server.

After some research I figured a simple string value can be passed using hidden value. However this wasn't possible with an array. If you could provide me an example/idea of how I could pass the array, it'd be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: convert array to string with `JSON.stringify(myArray)` and pass string value as hidden value

Comment: @ShishirArora Worked for me! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could post it using AJAX and then treat it as a web method in your code behind

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/yourpagename.aspx/ReadMyArray',
    data: { TheArray : YourArrayData },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) {

    },
    error: function (resp) {

    }
});
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool ReadMyArray(object TheArray)
{
    //handle TheArray
}
```